# file structure and init method for webjob/function using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

am a beginner in python and wants to test some code in webjob and function app. usually i write code using c# so in visual studio we have templates to create webjob/function app so that we get all required files and init code. Now using python i need the required file structure and init code.

Comment: What type of function you are trying to create?. HTTP Trigger, Time Triggert etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **folder/file structure** for a Python Functions project looks like:

```
<project_root>/
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - my_first_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - my_second_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - shared_code/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 | - tests/
 | | - test_my_second_function.py
 | - .funcignore
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - Dockerfile
```

#### init method for webjob/function using python

```
init__.py
import azure.functions as func
import logging


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,
         obj: func.InputStream):
logging.info(f'Python HTTP triggered function processed: {obj.read()}')
```

Please follow [developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux,application-level) of Azure functions using python and [Python Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python) using VS Code.